# Rails f.select include blank not VPAT compliant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, accessibility

I have this code in an html.erb view:

```
<%= f.select :info, grouped_options_info(@info), include_blank: true %>
```

The HTML code generated is this:

```
<select name="q[info]" id="info">
<option value=""></option>
<optgroup label="3"><option value="3,">All</option>
<option value="3,1">Above</option>
<option value="3,2">Bellow</option>
etc...
```

The issue is that when I test my code for VPAT compliance in this site:
https://validator.w3.org/

I get this error:

```
Error: Element option without attribute label must not be empty.
```

I should have something like this in the empty option: [reference](https://rocketvalidator.com/html-validation/element-option-without-attribute-label-must-not-be-empty)

```
<option value="m" label="medium"></option>
```

How can I add a label to the blank option in the select?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label can be passed in as a string.

Instead of `include_blank: true` you can use `include_blank: "Unselected"` for instance.

Comment: That worked, I used include_blank: "-" and now the report passed. Thank you so much!!